# Best way to apply conditional statement to layout update?

Tags: layout, xml, controllers

Ok, so i'm trying to show a certain link in the customer account area only if a customer is a particular group.

I can get the link to show by:

```
<customer_account>
    <reference name="customer_account_navigation" >    
        <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="mymodule"><name>module link</name><path>mymodule/account</path><label>Module Link</label></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

But how could I apply a conditional statement to this to only get this to show based on a customer group?

My thoughts are:

```
public function accountAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() && Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId() == 3){
        // edit layout?
    }
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace `// edit layout?` with

```
$navBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('customer_account_navigation');
if ($navBlock) {
    $navBlock->addLink(
         Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Module Link'),
         Mage::getUrl('mymodule/account'),
         Mage::helper('mymodule')->__('Module Link')
    );
}
```